# Controlling external visibility of Knowledge record Summary field through page layouts

Tags: knowledge, lightning-knowledge

We are running a Knowledge site,  and we have two page layouts for Articles.  One internal and one external.  It looks like the Summary field is always visible on the published Knowledge site, even though it is not on the external layout.  Has anyone encountered this?  Bug or expected behavior?

Comment: In my knowledge site implementation, guest users are not able to see the Summary field as it is not added to the External page layout. The only thing I can think of is, can you double check by going to the site guest user profile that they are assigned the external page layout and not the internal page layout by mistake?

Comment: I did check and the Summary field is not on the External page layout for the Guest user.  Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a separate field called Internal Summary for this precise purpose.  There was no way to prevent the Summary field showing up on the external layout so I made that field the public field and the other field is only on the internal layout.